# How can I access Success/Failure cases from this struct?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

[image]

Using Alamofire v4.0, `Alamofire.upload()` using `MultipartFormData` has changed, but I can't find out how to get the success/error case with the enumeration returned in the closure (type is `SessionManager.MultipartFormDataEncodingResult`)

Looking into the `SessionManager.MultipartFormDataEncodingResult` struct, here is what I get:

```
public enum MultipartFormDataEncodingResult {
    case success(request: UploadRequest, streamingFromDisk: Bool, streamFileURL: URL?)
    case failure(Error)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So Xcode seems to have been super unhelpful here and autocompleted the initialiser for that enum rather than the case statement. You would want to do something similar to what you have for the `.failure` case:

```
switch encodingResult {
case .success(let request, let streamingFromDisk, let streamFileURL):
    // you can now access request, streamingFromDisk and streamFileURL in this scope
    ...
case .failure(let errorType):
    // you can now access errorType in this scope
    ...
}
```